# SQLite inserting large number of records

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android app I am trying to insert 60 records via one sql command

```
INSERT INTO table (title, type, name, location) VALUES
('title_1', 'type_1', 'name_1', 'location_1'),
('title_2', 'type_2', 'name_2', 'location_2'),
('title_3', 'type_3', 'name_3', 'location_3'),
.....
('title_60', 'type_60', 'name_60', 'location_60');
```

But, it gives me an error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: all VALUES must have the same number of terms (code 1)
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: You must execute 60 inserts (in a loop). Possibly, under a transaction.

Comment: why don't you try adding with `ContentValues`....

Comment: Bob Malooga, you mean I must every time execute INSERTquery ? How it will influence on performance ?

Comment: you could start a transaction do all the inserts and then end the transaction as @BobMalooga said and this is not a performance issue

Comment: @ELITE can you give an example of using ContentValues ?

Comment: @gigs http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19 take a look at this

Comment: @gigs this is how to implement this http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/database-transactions

Comment: `you mean I must every time execute INSERTquery?` Of course. `How it will influence on performance?` Imperceivably. And it's the only way. Anyway, transactions will help in speeding up the batch.